# HTML output through JSON, activated by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, json

#### Background:

I have a page which dynamically pulls up a modal window, which displays extended information on a row (with multiple columns) through mySQL.  I am having issues where my JSON code will not populate the information correctly so that it can be outputted.  I have tried multiple nested arrays, while loops and for loops.  However, I only need to return one full row of information from the database.  After scratching my head, I am asking the help of all the SO experts.  Any pointers are much appreciated.

#### Ajax Code For Div Population (Works)

```
  var data_id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'view_agency_info.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id: data_id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.view_modal_content').html(data.html); // LOAD THE DATA INTO THIS DIV
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        $('.view_modal_content').html(''); // LOAD THE DATA INTO THIS DIV
                        alert('Error Loading Information');
                    }
                });
```

#### JSON Code To Pull Information and return HTML

```
<?php
$customer_id=$_SESSION['customer']['customer_id'];
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM collections_list WHERE id={$id} && customer_id=$customer_id LIMIT 1"; //expecting one row
$result = mysql_query( $query );
//$message = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ); //expecting just one row
$message=array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $message[]=$row['agency_name'];
    $message[]=$row['account_number'];
    $message[]=$row['phone'];
}

$json = array();
$json['html'] = '<p><pre><code>id:'.$id.'.<br>Agency Name: '.$message[0].'<br>Account Number:'.$message[1]."<br>Phone:".$message[2].'</code></pre></p>'.'<br><br>test';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $json );
?>
```

Additional Question:

> Is it possible to reference the headers in the array using " $message['agency_name'] "inside the html that gets returned?
>
> After solving this problem, I will need to turn the outputted html into a  structure to allow my users to view the information in a properly understandable format.  I know how to do this in html, but I am unfamiliar with JSON... Is there a way to output the information without having to manually code the structure?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Like a bad idea, you can also set field:
$json['data'] = array('id'=> $id, 'Agency Name', $message[0], 'Account Number' => $message[1], 'Phone' => $message[2]);
And use it later in JS like data.data :)

Comment: I apologize, I am a complete json&ajax newbie:  I understand what setting the array would do, but how in that instance could I use it to return FORMATTED HTML with the variables inserted?  Also, what advantage would that have for my particular implementation?

Comment: It is just dirty way of passing HTML thru json. Try to build html after you got JSON data.

Comment: why are you spitting out the rows in your php? bad practice use javascript to decode json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db(db_nname", $con);



$result = mysql_query("SELECT phone,agency_name FROM  '''' ");

 $rows = array();
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows['results'][] = $r;

 }

print json_encode($rows);


   ?>
```

and in your html

```
       <table id ="listtable"></table>

  var listdiv = $("#listtable");

      $.getJSON("whatever.php",function(json){
  $.each(json.results,function(i,data){ 
         listdiv.append("<tr><th>" + data.phone + "</th><th>" + data.agency_name + "</th></tr>");

    });     
      });
```

and in the append use data. and whatever your fields are
data.agency_name
data.phone

etc....

Comment: Ok, thats a clearer explanation of how it can be populated, but for example, in the html... how could I use this code to make a formatted table.  i.e.  <table><tr><td>Name: $name</td><td>Account: $account</td></table>

Comment: I may also point out that the reason why I can't output the full rows for your answer is because I am not going to use all columns for the populated information.  Any way to modify your code so that it only returns necessary columns, or would you just recommend to only use data.#1  data.#3  data.#5 for example

Comment: yes you limit the rows in your php select statement .  select phone, account_number from whatevertable ... or you can restrict it in js and just use this for the append......'look at edited code'

Comment: and just an fyi, web development is starting to veer away from the table structure, you can get the same look and a more flexible layout using lists.

Comment: `mysql_*` [functions are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php); [use PDO instead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Comment: @msanford working on completed beta development before redesigning the wheel (I've been preached to about this...  LOL, i Feel like its reteaching the wheel...)  I appreciate the comments tho :)